# Arithmetic overflow exception, On click event

Tags: vb.net

Arithmetic overflow exception occurs in the `vb.net` code follows :

```
Private Sub btnPlay_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPlay.Click, StartMonitoringToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Try
        Dim frmHome As Home = Me.MdiParent
        Dim Device As String = "U" & Hex(CType(Me.Tag, Home.NodeInfo).UnitNumber).ToString & "\G"
    End Try
End Sub
```

I checked the stack trace message. The message indicated the exception had occurred the line follows :

```
Dim frmHome As Home = Me.MdiParent
```

So I commented out this line, but the same exception occurred.

Then the stack stack massage indicated the exception occurred the line follows :

```
 Dim Device As String = "U" & Hex(CType(Me.Tag, Home.NodeInfo).UnitNumber).ToString & "\G"
```

How could I know the correct line occurring the overflow exception?
Why does Arithmetic overflow exception occurs?

Thanks.

Comment: I expect that Home.NodeInfo is the problem.

Comment: What is `UnitNumber`? Is it a field that holds a value, or a property/function that calculates a value?

Comment: What does the stack trace of exception indicate?

Comment: what do you mean by `Dim frmHome as **home** = ` ?

Comment: @Visual Vincent UnitNumber is  a field. Desclipted, Dim UnitNumber As Integer.Thanks.

Comment: @jmcilhinney The Stack Trace indicates a line number. The line number means the code line,  Dim frmHome As Home ... or  Dim Device As String = "U"... Thanks

Comment: @ Subaz Sarma To get MDI parent instane. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try splitting out the Hex calculation. I know I had some trouble with Hex returning the same, as it treats the objects differently, Try to dim your number as int, dbl or long or whatever you want first, then run the calculation and you'll be able to step through the code and see if / where its failing.

If your using visual studio, insert break points on each line (by clicking on the left side of the line of code) which should add a Red circle, when you run through your code, it will then halt at each place and you can press conitinue to carry onto the next line.

Hope this helps

```
    'Dim n As Long = CLng(CType(Me.Tag, Home.NodeInfo).UnitNumber)
    'Dim n As Double = CDbl(CType(Me.Tag, Home.NodeInfo).UnitNumber)
    Dim n As Integer = CInt(CType(Me.Tag, Home.NodeInfo).UnitNumber)
    Dim s As String = Hex(n)
    Dim Device As String = "U" & s & "\G"
```

Comment: Thank you for your graet advice. I Will try it when my problem happens again. After rebooted my computer, the exception does not occur no longer...